# There's a way to create a kind of Angular 2+ Component "Factory" and resolve it with ComponentFactoryResolver?

Tags: angular, typescript, class, inheritance, factory

I want to create a type of "factory" of Angular components and resolve it using the [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver). I mean, I have a component like:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    templateUrl: "./component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./component.scss"]
})
export class BaseComponent {

    property: string;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    // more stuff
}
```

I tried to do something like:

```
export class SomeKindOfWeirdFactory {
    static withProperty(property: string): new <T extends BaseComponent>() => any {
        class BaseComponetWithProperty extends BaseComponent {
            property: string = property;
        }
        return BaseComponetWithProperty as any;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
SomeKindOfWeirdFactory.withProperty("one property"); // BaseComponetWithProperty, but with "one property" as property.
SomeKindOfWeirdFactory.withProperty("other property"); // BaseComponetWithProperty, but with "other property" as property.
```

So, my problem is when I trying to resolve the component with the Angular Component Factory Resolver.

```
// other file.ts
const component = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeKindOfWeirdFactory.withProperty("the correct property"));
// ERROR Error: "No component factory found for BaseComponetWithProperty. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"
```

So, I tried to export the BaseComponentWithProperty class and import it to the NgModule and the entryComponents, but It doesn't work anyways.

```
// without this annotation the NgModule import has an error
@Component({
    templateUrl: "./component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./component.scss"]
})
export class BaseComponetWithProperty extends BaseComponent {
    property: string;
}

export class SomeKindOfWeirdFactory {
    static withProperty(property: string): new <T extends BaseComponent>() => any {
        class BaseComponetWithProperty extends BaseComponent {
            property: string = property;
        }

        return BaseComponetWithProperty as any;
    }
}

...
// other file.ts
const component = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeKindOfWeirdFactory.withProperty("the correct property"));
// Still no resolve the component
```

So, my question: Is this a bad practice? There's another way to do something like this?

Comment: Isn't easier to just expose a method to set that property on the BaseComponent.. then instance that component with its factory (obtained from the factory resolver) and setting its property calling that method?

Comment: You're totally right. I tried as you said and it was much easier in contrast of the way I was thinking about. Thank you!